# How can you handle the missing values in time series data?

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

I am recently working in some research project that deals with forecasting future data. However, I found that there are missing values of certain days (due to technological errors on those days) and have no record for those values. How can I handle those missing values, so that it will not affect the legitimacy of my report?

I actually thought of generating values by Newton interpolation for those missing values, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.